# Print to file via wofstream

Tags: c++, file, printing, wofstream

Below code does not work and give the compilation error of:

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error
>   invalid operands to binary expression ('std::wofstream' (aka 'basic_ofstream >'))

And the code is:

```
template <class T>
void printtofile(std::string filename, int mode, T var, std::wstring msg)
{
    wofstream outfile;
    if (mode == 0) outfile.open(filename); else outfile.open(filename, ios::out | ios::app);
    outfile << msg << L"\n";
    outfile << var << L"\n";
    outfile.close();
}
```

If I comment out the below line there is no error.

```
    outfile << var << L"\n";
```

Okay. The weird and confusing thing is that If I add the function with different parameters as the following there is no error although I do not comment out the line I mentioned above:

```
template <class T>
void printtofile(std::string filename, int mode, T var)
{
    wofstream outfile;
    if (mode == 0) outfile.open(filename); else outfile.open(filename, ios::out | ios::app);
    outfile << var << L"\n";
    outfile.close();
}
```

Isn't this the same thing? What is going on here?

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo It gives the error during compilation of the first code at the line: outfile << var << L"\n";

Comment: I made an answer instead to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `outfile << var << L"\n";` fails to compile, it's because `var` is of a type that doesn't have an overload like:

```
std::wofstream& operator<<(std::wofstream&, const T&);
```

If you for example try to pass a `std::string` to the function, that would cause the same error.

To make the error clearer for a user of the function, you can use SFINAE to only instantiate the template for supported types:

```
template<class T>
auto printtofile(const std::string& filename, int mode, T var,
                 const std::wstring& msg)
    -> decltype(std::wofstream{} << var, void()) {
//...
}
```

If you now try to use it with an unsupported type, the error will become something like:

```
error: no matching function for call to
 ‘printtofile(..., int, <the offending type>, std::wstring&)’
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Reproducing have been another problem for me. I am working on it. Regarding the line: outfile << var << L"\n"; It works fine in the second code part (overloaded function). This is weird.

Comment: You are welcome! Reproduce it by adding a `main()` where you call your function with the variable that causes the compilation error. I suspect that you haven't disclosed the full error message in the question. It _should_ reveal the type, so copy/paste it into the question in full. If the other function succeeds, you are not using the same type when calling that function.

Comment: You were right. I did not paste whole the error message because I thought it was not related. But after reproduced the code, I understood that It was related with it. I used Armadillo for matrix operations and it creates the problem.However It does not create the error if I use ofstream instead of wofstream.

Comment: @KC_ I _think_ you may be mixing types in your code that aren''t readily convertible - but I'm not sure since you've not made it clear yet. Make a small program that presents the problem and put another question up with that [mcve] and people will usually jump at it.

Comment: Yes you are right again; I used wstring and string types, together. And I realized wofstream does not print special unicode chacacters. Now I convert wstring to utf8 string and use ofstream instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to overload `<<` operator for type of `var` & for `std::string` you can reduce it to C style string and bypass the error.

Example:

`outfile<<msg.c_str()<<L"\n";`